# Enqueue a task in Google TaskQueue / Cloud Tasks from a Dataflow Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, task-queue

I need to read in a GCS file of 750K records.

For each record I need to compare it to a corresponding record in Google Datastore. If the record from the file does not match the record in Datastore, I need to update the Datastore record and enqueue a Taskqueue task.

The part I'm stuck on is launching this taskqueue task.

The only way seems to be via Google Cloud Task's HTTP api (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) but issuing a HTTP call from within a DoFn feels inefficient.

I looked into using pubsub for the task since dataflow has an adapter for that, but you can only use pubsub on streaming pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Beam doesn't seem to have special IO connectors for Cloud Task. So I guess you can only issue HTTP requests from inside a Beam DoFn.